# C# Not sure how to handle System.Web.HttpResponse

Tags: c#, azure

When I use this class on my local machine it prompts the user to open the xlsx file, but when I publish to Azure it no longer works.  I am pretty sure my problem it that I am not handling the filestream when on Azure.  Hopefully someone can help me out.

The code that works when I publish locally -

```
if (vm.ExportClicked != null && vm.ExportClicked.ToLower() == "true")
            {
                //doing this because I need the entire list not just a single page
                CustomerLastOrderListViewModel vm1 = new CustomerLastOrderListViewModel();
                var oPagedCustomerLists = oFilteredCustomerList.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id);

                //.ToList();
                List<CustomerLastOrderViewModel> customersLastOrders = CombineWithLastOrder(oPagedCustomerLists.ToList());
                vm1.CustomersLastOrder = customersLastOrders;
                DataTable dt = CreateCustomerEmailData(vm1, form);
                CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(dt, "CustomerEmailList.xlsx", HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Response);
```

I am using this response because I could not get it to compile with anything else.  The Excel class returns the information in a filestream and I am wondering since I am on Azure and Excel is not installed there I have to do something differently.

This is the CreateExcelDocument -

```
    public static bool CreateExcelDocument(DataTable dt, string filename, System.Web.HttpResponse Response)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            CreateExcelDocumentAsStream(ds, filename, Response);
            ds.Tables.Remove(dt);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Failed, exception thrown: " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

public static bool CreateExcelDocumentAsStream(DataSet ds, string filename, System.Web.HttpResponse Response)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, true))
        {
            WriteExcelFile(ds, document);
        }
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";

        //  NOTE: If you get an "HttpCacheability does not exist" error on the following line, make sure you have
        //  manually added System.Web to this project's References.

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        byte[] data1 = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(data1, 0, data1.Length);
        stream.Close();
        Response.BinaryWrite(data1);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Failed, exception thrown: " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code client or server side? I'm a little confused... Also where the hell is this `CreateExcelDocumentAsStream` method coming from? It doesn't appear to be part of .NET

Comment: Server side .. CreateExeclDoctumentAsStream is part of the excel class.  Will add above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CreateExcelDocument` try changing this;

```
CreateExcelDocumentAsStream(ds, filename, Response);
```

To;

```
CreateExcelDocumentAsStream(ds, filename, Response.OutputStream);
```

I'm pretty sure you're passing it an `HttpResponse` when it accepts a `Stream` (or at least I'm inferring that from the method name, I cannot find any documentation, so I'm assuming it's proprietary).